# How to control line under heading with image in rmarkdown's knitr outputs?

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

A line appears under a heading (#) in certain output formats (e.g. `output: github_document`) in R Markdown, but not in others. Is there a way to control this parameter explicitly?

Desired output, using

```
---
output: github_document
---
```

[image: github_document]

Output using:

```
---
output: html_document
---
```

[image: html_document]

Output using:

```
---
output: distill::distill_article
---
```

[image: distill::distill_article]

My ideal would be to replicate the output of github_document (with the line underneath, and the text beside the image) in the distill_article format, but I would also settle just for replicating the line in html_document format.

Full code for the target output below:

```
---
output: github_document
---

<style>
body {text-align: justify}
</style>

# distill for R Markdown <img src="rmarkdown.png" align="right" height="200" style="margin-left: 60px" />

This is some text underneath of the title. Lasciate ogne speranza voi ch'entrate. I grow old, I grow old. I shall wear the bottoms of my trousers rolled. Shall I part my hair behind? Do I dare to eat a peach? I shall wear white flannel trousers and walk upon the beach. I have heard the mermaids singing each to each.

I do not think that they will sing to me.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dashed line `----`  to get the same effect:

```
# distill for R Markdown 

--------------------------------------------------------------

This is some text underneath of the title. Lasciate ogne speranza voi ch'entrate. I grow...
```

## distill for R Markdown

---

This is some text underneath of the title. Lasciate ogne speranza voi ch'entrate. I grow...

Here is the html output with image:

[image]